# How i can save settings to the application Settings?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I created a new cell called it MySettings

[MySettings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dULzg.jpg)

The type is string the scope is user.

And in this place i want to store the last selected path:

```
private void btnDirectory_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FolderBrowserDialog MyDialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            MyDialog.SelectedPath = lblDirectoryName.Text;

            if (MyDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                lblDirectoryName.Text = MyDialog.SelectedPath;
            }
        }
```

Right after the line

```
MyDialog.SelectedPath = lblDirectoryName.Text;
```

I want to store the MyDialog.SelectedPath to MySettings
I tried to type: Properties.Settings. but i have there some options the first Default. But where is MySettings ?

And where and how i load back the saved settings ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 if (MyDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
  {
    lblDirectoryName.Text = MyDialog.SelectedPath;
    Properties.Settings.Default.MySettings=MyDialog.SelectedPath;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
  }
```

You can retrieve the store/saved value as following:

```
MyDialog.SelectedPath=Properties.Settings.Default.MySettings;
```